# How to add manually a device that udev adds then removes after plugged into USB port?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I'm trying to mount my cheap smart watch with a MTK6260A chipset to my PC in order to read the firmware contents. However while dmesg shows me that the device has been detected and created correctly:

```
[107204.279493] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[107204.280474] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Asking for cache data failed
[107204.280486] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[107204.281588] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

udev creates then removes it (from udevadm monitor):

```
KERNEL[107206.407012] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:80 (bdi)
KERNEL[107206.407083] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdf (block)
UDEV  [107206.407522] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:80 (bdi)
KERNEL[107206.408114] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/scsi_disk/12:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[107206.408199] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:80 (bdi)
KERNEL[107206.408241] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdf (block)
KERNEL[107206.408270] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [107206.408524] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/scsi_disk/12:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [107206.408806] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:80 (bdi)
KERNEL[107206.420107] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[107206.436186] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/scsi_host/host12 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[107206.436204] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12 (scsi)
UDEV  [107206.436828] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/scsi_host/host12 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [107206.470749] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdf (block)
UDEV  [107206.473577] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdf (block)
UDEV  [107206.474781] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [107206.475165] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12/target12:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [107206.475565] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/host12 (scsi)
```

Is there any way to add back the device manually?

Comment: First step would be to find out *why* the drive gets removed: If the kernel encounters an error while trying to access the device, it will remove it, which possibly could be what happens according to the log (remove originates from KERNEL). If that is the case, then no, you can't create it manually. The question is then why there are no error messages showing the problem.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the insight. Do you know how to debug udev? I was thinking in tapping the low level USB commands to get an idea, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

(I'll make this an answer and add to it, even though I don't have a ready-made solution. It's just too awkward in the comments.)

The problem is not `udev`, so "debugging udev" won't help. `udev` just reacts to the signal coming at .408114 from the kernel.

Assuming there are no other messages in `dmesg` than you have shown (which means "none at all", not "none you think are related", otherwise please edit question with the part before and after your snippet), all we know is that the kernel tries to send commands to the smart watch to find out more about the storage device, and both (write protection and cache) fail. After that, the kernel possibly does more interaction, and finally decides that this is not an USB storage device, because it doesn't answer, or gives errors back. So the kernel removes it from the storage layer, sends a signal to `udev`, and `udev` does what it should and removes the device nodes. Even if you'd prevent `udev` from removing the device nodes, they won't be present on the kernel level, so they'll be useless.

What you can do is to use `usbmon` to sniff the USB packets between the PC and the smartwatch. `wireshark` can interpret those. If you want to debug this, you'll need to read up on how USB works, how USB storage works, and how the SCSI commands that make the USB storage layer up work. This may or may not give a hint at what goes wrong. The standards are not difficult to find with a bit of googling.

It's also possible that the cheap smart watch just doesn't implement the USB storage standard correctly, and has a special Windows driver written by the manufacturer which hides that fact. In that case, you can also sniff the USB traffic on Windows to find out how it works, but then you'll have to write your own Linux kernel or userspace driver for it, which is a lot of work.